# How to enable auto horizontal and vertical scroll in spring shell console output?

Tags: scroll, spring-shell

I am  using Spring Shell.

When I try to run it in command prompt, output is longer than command prompt length and lines break to next line.
**How can I enable scroll or auto scroll for it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this has nothing to do with Spring Shell. This is rather a feature of your terminal program, so you should be looking for a setting regarding "buffer width", *etc.*

Comment: Thanks. how can I enable command prompt auto scroll in default size?